# Bootstrap table first element shifted

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a table with bootstrap in my Rails web app, but the first element of my line is always far away from the others.

[image]

I checked my CSS file and when I clear these lines (and just that) :

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

... the table is docked to the right. So obviously I guess that Bootstrap tables aren't working in my app, and I don't understand why. I took tables from internet and I have the same problem.

Here is my table in the html.erb file :

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="label">Tâche</th>
          <th class="label">Responsable</th>
          <th class="label">Durée</th>
          <th class="label">Date de début</th>
          <th class="label">Date de fin</th>
          <th class="label">Date de début standard</th>
          <th class="label">Date de fin standard</th>
          <th class="label">Retard</th>
          <th class="label">Congés</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @projectTasks.each do |task| %>
          <tr>
            <td class="task"><%= task[0] %></td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[1] %></td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[3] %> days</td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[4] %></td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[5] %></td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[6] %></td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[7] %></td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[8] %> days</td>
            <td class="task"><%= task[9] %> days</td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

... but I think that the problem is not here, like I said.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What browser? Is there any other CSS that is styling the table, including inline styles from javascript?

Comment: Is the problem still there when you remove the class 'task' and/or 'label'? Label is a bootstrap property, I think that might be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove class 'label' from the the table headers. You are accessing a class in bootstrap that is creating the visuals you are seeing.